# jquery .each function conflicts when changing DOM

Tags: javascript, jquery, each, tampermonkey

Does anyone have a clue why this function only works partially in both scenarios (with tampermonkey extension)

Html:

```html
<div class="container">
  <p>
    <a onclick="alert('item clicked')" class="">Element to auto click</a>
    <a href="myurl/telechargement">Element to open in new tab</a>
  </p>
</div>
```

Version 1:

```js
setTimeout(function(){
    $('.container a[href*="telechargement"]').each(function() {
         $(this).attr("target", "_blank"); //not working
         console.log(this) // see image bellow
         $(this).prev()[0].click(); //working
    });
}, 1000);
```

Version 2 (almost identical):

```js
setTimeout(function(){
    $('.container a[href*="telechargement"]').each(function() {
         $(this).attr("target", "_blank"); //working
         console.log(this) // see image bellow (same result)
         $(this).prev().click(); //not working
    });
 }, 1000);
```

[image]

The console returns `target="_blank"` in both scenarios, but on the first scenario the DOM has not changed, so there is no target attribute. Why does it behave like this?

It seems to work in fiddle so I might be looking in the wrong place https://jsfiddle.net/n71w52hy/2/
. Could this come from TamperMonkey? Any suggestion welcome.

Thanks hips.

Comment: I'm failing to see the difference between `$(this).attr("target", "_blank");` and `$(this).attr("target", "_blank");`

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @freedomn-m there is none. The difference is here:  `$(this).prev()[0].click();` and  `$(this).prev().click();`. When  `$(this).prev()[0].click();` is successfull, the target attribute is not added to the dom, but if I remove  `$(this).prev()[0].click();` , the target attibute is added.

@Myerffoeg I need to auto click on previous <a> element and open the <a> element in a new tab.